# Can Storage Spaces drives be moved to a SAS controller without data loss?

Tags: sata, controller, storage-spaces, sas

I have an old file server with some 20 SATA drives attached to both mainboard and external controller cards. The machine is running Windows Server 2012 R2 and using Storage Spaces to pool the drives.

Can i move the drives from the old controller and onto the SAS Expander without Storage Spaces freaking out? I know you can move pooled drives between machines without problems but now I am moving from SATA controller to SAS controller. Will the LSI card pass the drives through "as-is" so that Storage Spaces can identity the drives and see that its the old drives.

I have now bought the following new hardware:
X-Case RM 424 Pro 24-bay Hotswap 6 Gbit/s Backplane
LSI SAS 9207-4i4e
HP SAS Expander 6 Gbit/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been tested and works when moving drives to a SAS HBA controller.
SAS Raid controller has *not* been tested.